# Get multiple results as output for one condition on numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking for a way to get multiple results for one condition of a numpy array.
Currently, I run the same `where`  condition twice on the same numpy array, to get two new arrays with different output.

```
import numpy as np
np_array = np.random.rand(3,3)
entry_array = np.where(np_array>=0.5,1,0)
mod_array = np.where(np_array>=0.5,np_array,0)
```

Does a possibility exists where I can fill the two new arrays `entries, mod_array` with only one loop over `np_array`.
Additionally, I am also looking for a solution for non-array output, like the following.

```
entries = np.where(np_array>=0,1,0).sum()
sum_entries = np.where(np_array>=0,np_array,0).sum()
```

I am especially interested in an efficient way, as my arrays have more than 100 million entries.

Comment: `Additionally, I am also looking for a solution for non-array output`, could you clarify what a non-array output is?

Comment: I don't know of any solution to do both operations in only one step, but you could at least reduce the calculation time by generating a single boolean mask with `mask = np_array >= 0.5` and then use this for boolean indexing.

Comment: Second part of Q: `entries = np.count_nonzero(np.array>=0.5)` `sum_entries = np.sum(np_array,where=np.array>=0.5)`

Comment: @yatu With non-array output I was referring to output, where an additional operation is performed on the array with the condition and only single value is returned. Like the `sum()` in the second code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few similar ideas:

```
def m1(np_array):
  entry_array = np.where(np_array>=0.5,1,0)
  mod_array = np.where(np_array>=0.5,np_array,0)
  return mod_array, entry_array

def m2(np_array):
  mod_array = np.where(np_array>=0.5,np_array,0)
  entry_array = np.array(mod_array, dtype=bool)+0
  return mod_array, entry_array

def m3(np_array):
  entry_array = np_array<0.5
  np_array[entry_array] = 0
  return np_array, 1-entry_array
```

Comparison: **m1** seems slightly slower (up to 2x) than **m2** and **m3**.

```
in_ = [np.random.rand(n,n) for n in [10,100,1000,10000,20000]]
```

[image]